# How to use Google Spreadsheet ADDRESS function to create a range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying yo create a formula in google spreadsheet that calculates the maximum value for all the cells above the current cell, in a way I can copy it to any cell and still workss. I tried using the ADDRESS function like this:

```
=MAX(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()):ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN()))
```

But I get an parse error. I tried many variants of this code, but always get an error. Apparently, the ADDRESS function is not allowed as part of a range.

Is there any way to create a reference to a range based on the current cell position?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Was stuck on something very similar. Something like this should work.

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(1, COLUMN()) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Here are my two formulas. The first is the one using your technique and the second is what currently works: =SUMIF(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN()+1, 4) & ":2", "Total * Direct", D4:4)
=SUMIF(D2:2, "Total * Direct", D4:4)

Answer (score 5):

This might be useful too if you want to get the sting address for a range:

`=ADDRESS(row(A3:A6),COLUMN(A3:A6))&":"&ADDRESS(row(A3:A6)+rows(A3:A6)-1,COLUMN(A3:A6)+COLUMNS(A3:A6)-1)`

This will return a string on the range, in this case

`$A$3:$A$6`

Answer (score 4):

Using the INDIRECT function on your range string returns a range reference, which can then be used in a formula, eg.

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()):ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN()))
```

should work in

```
MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN()):ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN())))
```